# Reference ValueConverter from XAML page in MAUI app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am trying to use the BoolToObject converter class referenced here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/bool-to-object-converter

In my XAML page I included the following line

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">
```

I am trying to use it like as indicated in the reference page like so:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToObjectConverter" TrueObject="42" FalseObject="0" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

But it says the type "BoolToObjectConverter" can not be found. What am I missing?

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: have you added the nuget packages?

Comment: I forgot about it, I have now added the nugget package and get a new error: cannot resolve type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit:toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `.NET MAUI Community Toolkit` package, you need to call the extension method in your `MauiProgram.cs` file as follows:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        
        // Initialise the toolkit
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();

        // the rest of your logic...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was indeed missing this call. I had also mistakenly installed the CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core instead of CommunityToolkit.Maui package, so I included that in my answer as well for other people to see. Thanks again for your help have a good day

Answer (score 1):

For those facing a similar issue, here are the two things I had to do to resolve the issue:

- Install CommunityToolkit.Maui package. I had mistakenly installed CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core instead.
- As mentioned by Alexandar, make sure to call the extension method in MauiProgram.cs:

  builder.UseMauiApp().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();